# MVC 4 Single Page Application - Where's the data go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-spa

I just created an ASP.NET MVC 4 single page application using the template.

Out of the box it appears to be able to persist and retrieve data. But I can't work out where this data is going. I haven't set up a database or anything.

```
    public void InsertSubscription(Models.Subscription entity) {
        InsertEntity(entity);
    }
```

After I call this function. Where can I go to view the table with the data in it?

Answer (score 2):

Look in your application's `web.config` file for a database connection string. That should point to where your data is located.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SPA template creates a SQL Server Express database stored in your application's `App_Data` folder.

[This article](http://www.tikalk.com/data-sourcelocaldbv110) provides information about the default setup.